# Can SignalR be used with oracle database?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, signalr

I need to implement push technology in my application. I need to display data on the web page as it gets inserted in the database in realtime.

I am using ASP.NET with oracle 11G and 12c as a backend database. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use SignalR with ORACLE?

Does SignalR have any dependency on the backend database? Or could it be used with any database?

I tried but oracle change event not working in the hub.

Answer (score 2):

SignalR is a framework to allow easy usage of websockets (with fallback on other tranport options). There is a frontend part in JavaScript and a backend for .NET, that allows calls from server to clients. It has no dependency on any database technology. You can use Entity Framework or ADO.NET to access any database supported by .NET. Oracle is no problem.